# Fetch select option when editing the post

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show the selected category in the edit form But it is not showing,

My view :

```
   <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('category_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">

                    {{--<option value="">Choose Category</option>--}}

                    @foreach($cat as $category)
                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>

                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

the edit method in my `PostController` :

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $cat = Category::all();

        return view('admin.posts.edit',['post'=>$post,'cat'=>$cat]);
    }
```

I tried to put an if statement like this :

```
  @foreach($cat as $category)
                        <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{$category->id == App\Category::class ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>

                    @endforeach
```

It is showing a category However it's not the selected category for the post.

HELP

Comment: check if the the category_id passed is equal to the category id of the select, then make it as selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$category->id == App\Category::class
```

You're comparing the id of the category with the name of the class here.

What you want to do is probably this:

```
$category->id == $post->category_id
```

Comment: Yep that was the problem Thanks

Comment: No sweat. Glad it was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

check request by category id and if it is same echo selected.

`@foreach($cat as $category)
    <option value="{{$category->id}}" @if(request()->category_id==$category->id) selected @endif>{{$category->name}}</option>
@endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve it as a the defined select:

```
   <select name="category_id" id="category_id" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('category_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}">
                <option value="{{ post->category->id }}" name="{{ $post->category->name }}">
                @foreach($cat as $category)
                    <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>

                @endforeach
            </select>
```

This will now be the default option and the loop will still be in the dropdown